# Expanding on django forms

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have a modelform, which has three required fields: `user`, `network`, and `position`. The `position` is pulled by `request.POST`, and the other two will be supplied outside of it. This is what I currently have:

```
form = StartForm(request.POST)
form.save()
```

Obviously, this form is not validating, because I haven't provided the `user` and `network` instances. How do I add this additional information to the form? Conceptually, I'm looking for something like this:

```
form = StartForm(request.POST + user_id=10, network_id=20)
form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something similar to: `form = StartForm(position = request.POST, user_id = 10, network_id = 20)`?  You might have to print the value for request.POST since I think it's actually a list.  So just find out what position is in the request.POST

Comment: You'll get and error on `StartForm(position = request.POST, user_id = 10, network_id = 20)` because `ModelForm` does not have `position`, `user_id` and `network_id` keyword arguments.

Comment: `request.POST` is a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options there:

1. `user` and `network` fields are not allowed to come from `request.POST`. For example if `user` should be the currently logged in user which comes from `request.user`.

   In that case you can do:

   ```
   class StartForm(form.models.ModelForm):

       class Meta:
           model = MyModel
           fields = ["position", ] # You don't include user and network to the form

   form = StartForm(request.POST, instance=MyModel(user=user, network=network))
   ```

   So you initialize the form with a model which has pre-filled fields.
2. `user` and `network` fields are allowed to come from `request.POST`. Then you do:

   ```
   form = StartForm(request.POST, initial={"user": user, "network": network})
   ```

   Note that in this case `user` and `network` fields may be overriden by values which come from `request.POST`.